# In Android Activity Toolbar is not getting inflate

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-toolbar

I was able to successfully replace existing ActionBar with Toolbar. But after inflating menu; menu bar is not appearing. The same functionality is working with existing ActionBar (Without Toolbar).

I tried including tbMain.inflateMenu(); as well but no luck.

MainActivity.java

```
package me.creatorguy.androidtoolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar tbMain = findViewById(R.id.tbMain);
        setSupportActionBar(tbMain);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tbMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:textColorPrimary="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:subtitle="This is subtitle"
    app:subtitleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:title="Smit's Android Toolbar"
    app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: The `android:id` on the `<include>` overrides the `android:id` on the root `View` in the included layout, so your `Toolbar` is ending up with ID `include`, and `findViewById(R.id.tbMain)` is returning null. Either remove that `android:id` on the `<include>`, or change the `findViewById()` call to pass `R.id.include` instead.

Comment: Thanks. that worked.